# Do you have to put the UISearchBar in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I would like to use a UISearchBar and put it towards the bottom of a screen in order to search for available names through an API call.  I want to have this SearchBar as part of a sign up form.  However, when I put the SearchBar on the screen where I would like through the Storyboard, it does not show up when I run the app on the simulator.  When I looked up this issue, everyone is putting the searchbar in a tableview. Am I not using the correct UI element for my cause?

Comment: What's the parent view of the searchbar? It may be overlapped by the tableview or it has a fixed frame and displayed outside the screen.

Comment: I have put it in a stackView with a label that is on top of it

Answer (score 1):

The reason your search bar is not on the screen is probably because you didn't set constraint correctly or it was hidden or covered by some other view.

And for your second half of the question, I myself never put a search bar on a `UITableView` itself. Some apps put a search bar on the first cell of a table view but you have to scroll to make it show up. I myself always prefer to put it on the navigation controller on the top of the screen so that it will always be there and ready for user to search anything.

Comment: I have put it in a stackview. So there is a label and a searchbar underneath that label in a vertical stackview

Comment: @Keyshawn Sure that works. So you still trying to figure out why it's not showing up? Post your code and storyboard constraints of your search bar

Comment: I have no code for it yet. I have a stack view with text as the first element. The stack view is constrained to the leading and trailing margins of the superview. Center alignment and Equal Spacing distribution. The stackView is constrained to the top and bottom of two other vertical stackViews. Making it sandwhiched. Thats it. It wont show lol